# How can I give people view access to a Google Form so they can make a copy of it without editing the original?

Tags: google-drive, google-forms

My uncle works for a dog breeding company and asked me to create a survey for him with about 20 pages of questions. I finished the form using Google Forms and then he asked me to make a guide for other dog breeding clubs/groups to host their own version of this survey on their own account. I thought it would be non-trivial, I could just make this form public with view only, however it seems that the only sharing option is "can edit". I do not wish for the public to be able to make changes to the original form, only to be able to make a copy and they can make changes on their own copy.

The second option I had was to have my uncle reply to requests to edit the form for people he trusts so they can make a copy. However, my uncle doesn't think that he can trust every single leader of every dog breeding club to not tamper with the original file.

So is there any way I can just make my Google Form available to make a copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share the spreadsheet which holds form responses in view mode. They can make a copy of the spreadsheet which will also copy the form for them.

Comment: I believe a way not requiring giving access to the form answers is preferred.

Comment: Just delete the rows which holds form responses. You still have the form for others to copy from.

Comment: Yeah, if you create a copy of the spreadsheet (since you probably want to keep the answers as well).

Comment: I ended out just copying the forms myself for each of the clubs as he provided me with a list of the people to share to and I gave each of them access to their own. But yes, had I known this I would've gone with it, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I created an google form as a template on Google Drive. Then made the Google spreadsheet viewable to users. So they can copy the spreadsheet. I don't want users to edit my original form by mistake.

The issues is users can copy the spreadsheet to their own Google drive. But when they click on edit form from spreadsheet menu, they still go to my original form. So the spreadsheet they copied is still linked to my form, but not a new form.

Hope this makes sense.